# Entity Framework Core TPH with Discriminator in other table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In a usual TPH implementation, a table has a "Discriminator" column used by EF to decide which class to instantiate.
I have a db in which a the discriminator references another table, instead, containing a list of entity types and their relative codes.
How to configure the dbContext, so that the discriminator is now a field in the referenced table?

To simplify things, let's build a simple example: a table "Pets" containing a list of pets, implemented in concrete classes "Dog" and "Cat", both derived from "Pet". Class Cat has a field "Mews", indicating the number of mews; class Dog has a field named "Woovs".

**Typical implementation:**

The Pets table has an identity column "Id" (primary key), a "Discriminator" indicating the type of concrete class, a Mews and a Woovs fields.

The dbContext is instructed to instantiate the proper concrete class like this.

```
            modelBuilder
                .Entity<Pet>()
                .HasDiscriminator(c => c.Discriminator)
                .HasValue<Cat>("CAT")
                .HasValue<Dog>("DOG")
                ;
```

**My requirements:**

Another table exists, "PetTypes", with an identity column "Id" (primary key) and a "Code" column, with unique constraint.
The Pets table has no Discriminator column; it has a PetTypeId column, instead, referencing the PetTypes table (foreign key to PetTypes' Id column).

I would like to instruct the modelBuilder to use the PetTypes' Code property as discriminator; something like:

```
modelBuilder
                .Entity<Pet>()
                .HasDiscriminator(c => c.PetType.Code)
                .HasValue<Cat>("CAT")
                .HasValue<Dog>("DOG")
                ;
```

or:

```
modelBuilder
                .Entity<Pet>()
                .HasDiscriminator(c => c.PetType)
                .HasValue<Cat>(new PetType(Code = "CAT"))
                .HasValue<Dog>(new PetType(Code = "DOG"))
                ;
```

or some other way, so that the Pets class discriminator is agnostic ot the PetTypeId, but only deals with the PetType's code.

Is there any way to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

TPH can be configured just like a standard primary/foreign key relationship. You don't need the Code column, just set your discriminator column as an integer with a foreign key to the PetTypes table. Here's an example:

```
public abstract class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PetTypeId { get; set; }
    public PetType PetType { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Pet
{
    public int Mews { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Pet
{
    public int Woovs { get; set; }
}

public class PetType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pet>(builder => 
        { 
            builder.HasDiscriminator(p => p.PetTypeId)
                .HasValue<Cat>(1)
                .HasValue<Dog>(2);
            builder.HasOne(p => p.PetType)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p.PetTypeId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PetType>(builder => 
        {
            builder.HasKey(pt => pt.Id);
        });
    }
}
```

}

With this example, all the pets of type Dog will have a PetTypeId of 2 that refers back to the PetType of Dog.